# Simple confidence interval problem

Tags: statistics

Suppose that we are determining a 99% confidence interval for the population mean using our 15 pieces of data. If it assumed that we know the value of the standard deviation $\sigma$, what is the chart (table) number that we plug into the appropriate formula for this problem?

Would this be a z-score or t-score? Also, would there be 14 or 15 degrees of freedom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In making a confidence interval (CI) for the mean $\mu$ of a normal population based on a random sample $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ from that population:

$1.$ Use z if the population standard deviation (SD) $\sigma$ is a *known* number.
(No degrees of freedom parameter for a normal distribution.) A 95% CI is of
the form
$$\bar X \pm 1.96\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

$2.$ Use t if the population SD $\sigma$ is *unknown* and estimated by the sample
SD $S.$ If the sample has $n$ observations, then the degrees of freedom are $\nu = n-1.$  A 95% CI is of
the form
$$\bar X \pm t^*\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}},$$
where $t^*$ cuts 2.5% from the upper tail of Student's t distribution with
$ \nu = n-1$ degrees of freedom.  For example, if $n = 15,$ then $\nu = n - 1 =14$ and $t^* = 2.145.$